# HTML - image buttons

Tags: html, image, button, hyperlink

i am currently making a HTML table and attempting to link each picture to a different part of my web. This is what i currently have. The first Tire pressure button and the second brake light buttons work, but for some reason, my first brake light button wont work. I'm having this issue throughout my table, and this is just a part of the whole in case you're wondering if i created my table completely.

```
<tr>
<th> Tire Pressure </th>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<a href="#3" onclick="do_button_click(16, 6, 'Tire Pressure',0);"><img src="https://zingtree-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/images/596e3972ca3f94.79429781-53455-TPS+sensor.png" style="width: 180px; height: 180px;"></a>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th> Brake Light </th>
<td style='text-align: center;">
<a href="#3" onclick="do_button_click(7, 6, 'Brake',0);"><img src="https://zingtree-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/images/596e3972ca3f94.79429781-498613-Brake+light.png" style="width: 180px; height: 180px;"></a>
</td>
<td style="text-align: center;">
<a href="#3" onclick="do_button_click(7, 6, 'Brake',0);"><img src="https://zingtree-uploads.s3.amazonaws.com/images/596e3972ca3f94.79429781-849684-brake+light+v2.png" style="width: 180px; height: 180px;"></a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: It seems in the <td> tag below brake light you are using both single and double quotes. That should correct your problem, and I am guessing that is why only the two are working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that you made a very subtle typo on the following line:

```
<td style='text-align: center;">
```

It should be:

```
<td style='text-align: center;'>
```

I used jsfiddle.net to check the syntax, by the way, so prior to posting to StackOverflow I would check your code there first or in any standard HTML syntax checker to ensure your issue isn't a simple syntax error.

Comment: wow i feel so dumb haha! thank you so much really appreciate that catch!